# Read xml tag value from oracle using sql developer

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

```
<wbi:appData>
    <wbi:content wbi:name="1st_status">
        <wbi:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Success</wbi:value>
        </wbi:content>
    </wbi:appData>
</wbi:event>
```

I need to get the value "1st_status" which is in 2nd line and "Success" which is in 3rd line using SQL developer.

this xml is in a table which has a column in the form of CLOB type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do it like this:

(ie table `yourdata` contains a clob column `c`)

```
SQL> select extractvalue(xmltype(c), '/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content/@wbi:name','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"') name,
  2         extractvalue(xmltype(c), '/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content/wbi:value','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"') status
  3    from yourdata
  4  /

NAME            STATUS
--------------- ---------------
1st_status      Success
```

this assumes you wbi namespace is xmlns:wbi="http://foo"

if //content is a repeating tag, then you do this instead:

```
SQL> select extractvalue(value(t), '/wbi:content/@wbi:name','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"') name,
 2         extractvalue(value(t), '/wbi:content/wbi:value','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"') status
 3    from yourdata,
 4         table(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(c), '/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content', 'xmlns:wbi="http://foo"'))) t
 5
SQL> /

NAME            STATUS
--------------- ---------------
1st_status      Success
2nd_status      Failure
```

Comment: Also i wanted to know if there is any way to check if the "wbi:value" tag exits in the xml ?????

Comment: @user1627561 of course. there's the existsnode function for that

Comment: @user1627561 eg `existsnode(xmltype(c), 'your xpath', 'xmlns:wbi="http://foo"')`. 1 = exists, 0 = it does not. you can use that in the select or where clause.

Comment: inside the trigger with table name say "tab_a" can i mention "tab_a" again inside select statement.

Comment: `value1:=l_xmltype.extract('wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content/@wbi:name/text()',xmlns:wbi="http://foo").getStringVal();`
Pls help, i am trying by using this statement but i am not gettin the value for name but the same i am getting for status.

Answer (score 0):

you can try ::

```
SELECT extractvalue(xmltype(xmlcol), 'xpath') FROM yourtable
```

But need to check if xmltype works for CLOB data type.

Comment: XPath models an XML document as a tree of nodes.